# Google Cloud Kubernetes reservations

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine

Recently our GKE environment was suspended. When the account was re-activated Kubernetes was not working because only 1 of 3 servers were available. Two zones reported ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED for 30 minutes until we added a new node pool.

We are told by Google this is normal and we should use reserved instances. I'm doubtful that reserved instances would have fixed the issue as I'm sure a reserved instance would have been terminated when the account was suspended.

I find it hard to believe that reserved instances are required when creating a GKE cluster.

My concern is not why the server went down but that GKE could not recover without manual intervention. If it was required I would hope that the GCP console would do this automatically. And so that is why I'm asking the experts on Server Fault:

- Should I be creating a Kubernetes cluster and then separately reserving instances?
- Would a reserved instance help fix issues like a server crash, updates, or any normal operation where machines are unavailable.
- Google states "With reservations, 95% of VMs start in less than 120 seconds". This does not sound like the instance is reserved. Are the instances actually reserved or is there a 5% chance GKE cannot recover by itself?
- Should every VM instance (not just GKE) have both an "Instance Group" and a "Reserved Instance"?
- Is there another solution?

I really don't want to move the cluster back to AWS as GKE is so feature-rich. But at the moment I don't have confidence with GKE. Your feedback is much appreciated.

**Edit 17/2/2024**

I thought I would simplify my question as I may not be describing the problem well enough.

I was told by Google to use reserved instances to avoid ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED.

Reserved instances sound like Google somewhat hold your machine with a 95% of getting a machine within 2 minutes. To me, reserved instances sound like certainty when turning off and on a VM machine.

If I do not stop an instance, say there is a machine failure or a recovered VM outage in Google do reserved instances fix the ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED issue?

**Edit 27/3/2024**

After talking to Google Support for 2 months I and having the issue escalated 3 times I was unable to resolve this issue.

Google support were unable to find a solution to ZONE_RESOURCE_POOL_EXHAUSTED for a zonal GKE cluster besides reserved instances. However, they were only able to confirm that we are only guaranteed (without SLA) an instance 95% of the time and were unable to confirm if we would even have priority on receiving a new instance if it became available.

I felt Google support worked quite hard on this case and apologized for our first session where they were unprepared. So I was quite happy with their service in the end. The initial support would not go outside public information, however I was disappointed with the escalated responses which were completely useless.

Comment: My comments on your other question still apply to this question. If you do not monitor, manage, and pay your bills you will have problems. AWS is no different.

Comment: Hey John, the billing may have been a stuff-up by another department for failing to recognise that by moving the billing account Google wouldn't bill their credit card until they manually pressed activate in the console. But my question is not about billing or the fact it went down, it is about coming back up. GKE could not spin up 3 "standard" servers. How do I know if a machine dies it will be able to recover? I don't want to wake up in the middle of the night to create a new node pool. I will update the question

Comment: I covered that also on your other question - use instance reservations. However, if you don't pay your bill then you are also not paying for reservations. Once your account is shutdown/terminated assume everything will be lost and you must start over. Google sent multiple emails warning about problems. Create a procedure so this issue does not happen again.

Comment: Thanks John for your help. Are you saying that any prod VM needs to be a reserved instance to be a prod setup? For instance, say I have a VM instance with a hardware failure - do I need to reserve an instance to ensure I get a new machine?

Comment: Read the Google documentation on reservations for the details. There are many items that you must manage: https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/instances/reservations-overview

Comment: Thank you @JohnHanley for your comments. I have been in conversations with Google Support for the last 2 months and we couldn't come up with a non-manual solution. Reserved instances seem like a good solution however Google only guarantees (without SLA) that you will get an instance 95% of the time. I was unable to get an answer to what happens the other 5% of the time.